# Cannot get the available bytes from the unix domain socket

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, unix-socket

I am sending N bytes from a unix domain socket (AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM) to another. However, if I read X bytes from the other socket, where X < N, a subsequent call to read() blocks and I cannot get the rest of the N-X bytes.

Is this an expected behaviour for unix domain sockets? Is the rest of the N-X bytes thrown by the kernel. Is there a solution, such as a socket option?

Comment: What are those sockets - UDP or TCP?

Comment: The socket I use is (AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you are observing is not specific to `AF_UNIX` sockets. It is specific to `SOCK_DGRAM` sockets. The distinctive property of datagram sockets is that they are message-oriented.

Unlike TCP sockets, every time you call `send()` or `sendto()` on a datagram socket, you are creating a single **message**. You should read the whole message with a single `recv()` or `recvfrom()` call. Whatever was not read, is discarded, and next call to `recv()` will give you the next message on the wire.

If stream-oriented communication is desired, `SOCK_STREAM` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send messages of unknown length and never discard data, you have two options:

1. `SOCK_DGRAM`: Call `getsockopt` with `SO_NREAD` before every read to size your buffer appropriately.
2. `SOCK_STREAM`: Manually parse message boundaries (e.g. length header or null terminator).

An additional difference (which is often more significant) is that stream sockets are connection-oriented whereas datagram sockets are connectionless. `SOCK_SEQPACKET` is essentially a connection-oriented `SOCK_DGRAM`, but I don't think it's as widely available.